# LCD signal splitter and repeater

Tags: lcd, relay, microcontroller

I am looking to build a circuit board that can take a multi segment LCD display signal from a ZIF connector, relay it, and split it to another LCD while having the original and seperate LCD display.

Anyone have experience on this, and are their chipsets that do this already?

Comment: Actually a ZIF connector is irrelevant if it's been done on another bus, this is just a physical layer.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're trying to make two displays show the same thing at the same time?

Do you have a part number for the display?

Comment: Yes I am trying to display on two displays at the same time, I do not have the LCD part number. It's a black box at the moment. The driver chip is potted.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just run wires in parallel to each LCD. It might draw too much current, but LCDs generally draw very little current, so there's a good chance it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to just wire them together, however i would include provisions for signal reflection issues.

Don't split the signal going to them, but rather run the signal to one, then to the other and allow space past the last display to include end termination if needed.

Your limits on the number of displays will be the drive current, length of the signal lines and total bus capacitance.

Answer (score 0):

does the LCD have an onboard controller? probably not, but I figured I would mention that if it does you will have to run individual wires for an enable lines or similar.